# iPhone app with Core Data. How do I connect and exchange data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data

How is the information handled between server and app? I have a `Core Data` database in my app. I would do it like that (please tell me if that is inappropriate or if you think there are better ways): I would first create an Sqlite database on my server. Whenever the user opens the app, all the data is fetched from the database and written into the `Core Data` database and available to use inside the app. If a user wants to write something to the SQLite database, I would write it to the database via JSON.
How does that sound ? How do others do it ? What is the most effective way to achieve the tasks at hand ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL database on the server end, then use PHP or some other server side language to pull data from the database and assemble it into a properly formatted JSON String.

On the iOS side, implement a JSON parsing framework like this one hosted by google.
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Basically your JSON Arrays will result in `NSArrays` and Key->Values will get collected into an `NSDictionary`. You can parse it like this.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"object\":{"\key\":\"value\"}}";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
```